# How to show text view with dotted text and also horizontal scroll

Tags: android, android-widget

this is my layout

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarFadeDuration="5">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/documentName"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Untitled Document123456789"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Case 1: When i use text view alone, it shows Untitled Document... (...)denoting some text is hidden but i didn't get the horozontal scroll. Then i surround text view with horizontal scroll, i got the scroll but not the dotted text denoting some text is hidden

Please correct my layout if am missing anything.

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to do. I din't understand your question.

Comment: my text view width is 175dp, if the text exceeds, i should able to scroll horizontally.

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content" instead of 175dp. try this

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your textview

```
android:ellipsize="start"
```

Instead of start you can have other values: end, middle ... You can look up at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize